# How do I implement prefix sums in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am stuck trying to implement prefix sums in Hadoop. I understand the algorithm:

- each node has its 'bucket' of data
- each node sums the bucket
- each node broadcasts his sum to 'following' nodes
- each node can now sum the 'previous' data, and calculate prefix sum for each element in its bucket

But how do I implement it? How do I know how many nodes were used? How do I know which node 'am I'? Hadoop documentation is incredibly lacking in information and confusing. I wanted to broadcast the data by emitting the sum multiple times with key in range (nodeID, numberOfNodes), so that every reducer can sum it up. I feel lost, I don't have a lot of experience in Hadoop. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three tasks in Hadoop:

1. First task (with only one reducer)

   - Mappers sample data and send it as *(0, value)* pairs
   - Reducer reads from configuration as *r* number of reducers in future tasks, sorts data in ascending order and selects *r - 1* split points. Save them as *(null, value)*

   Let's say results are stored in *partition* directory on hdfs.
2. Second task (with *r* reducers)

   - Mappers read data from *partition* (there's only one file, at every line is a value of split point int ascending order) and save it in vector. Using binary search, map data to *(p, value)*, where *p* is a number from *0* to *r - 1* and represents reducer where data falls in.
   - Partitioners is an identity partitioner - for given pair *(key, value)* it sends it to *key* parititoner.
   - Reducer calculates number of values he got from mappers. Saves result as *(reducer, size)* pair.

   Let's say results are stored in *sizes* directory on hdfs.
3. Second task (with *r* reducers)

   - Mappers - the same as in task no. 2
   - Partitioners - the same as in task no. 2
   - Reducer reads the sizes of all reducer windows from *sizes* directory. The directory contains files with lines containing only pairs of integers - number of reducer and size of its data. Calculate total size of windows of reducers with smaller number than current reducer as *total*. Sort your data, and for *i*-th value save it as *(total + i, value)*